# How to aggregate multiple smart contract function calls on Rootstock?

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js, rsk

I have multiple ERC20 tokens, deployed on [Rootstock](https://developers.rsk.co/),
and I want to track their balances and allowances in a real time from my DApp.
In [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/),
I *can* track their balances by alternately calling the functions
`balanceOf(address)` and `allowance(owner, spender)`.
However, across two tokens, that equates to about
4 JSON-RPC requests every ~30 seconds.

I would prefer to reduce the frequency of JSON-RPC requests made by my application,
by aggregating these particular requests.

Is it possible to *combine* multiple smart contract data queries
into a single JSON-RPC request via `ethers.js` or any other library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a look at [`@0xsequence/multicall`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@0xsequence/multicall). It consists of:

- [MultiCallUtils smart contract](https://github.com/0xsequence/wallet-contracts/blob/master/src/contracts/modules/utils/MultiCallUtils.sol) with a `multiCall()` function intended for making aggregated calls
- [JS frontend library](https://github.com/0xsequence/sequence.js/tree/master/packages/multicall) which includes a Multicall wrapper around ethers.js provider.

#### Smart contract deployments:

- `MultiCallUtils` is deployed on the Rootstock Testnet: [`0xb39d1Dea1bF91Aef02484F677925904b9d6936B4`](https://explorer.testnet.rsk.co/address/0xb39d1dea1bf91aef02484f677925904b9d6936b4?__ctab=Code)
- I am not sure whether it is deployed at Rootstock Mainnet or not, anyway, you can deploy it there yourself.

#### To make aggregated smart contract calls:

1. Install the npm package:

```bash
npm i @0xsequence/multicall
```

2. Import the library to your project:

```js
const { providers } = require('@0xsequence/multicall');
```

3. Create a Rootstock Testnet configuration:

```js
const multicallConfig = {
  // RSK Testnet
  31: {
    // maximum number of calls to batch into a single JSON-RPC call
    batchSize: 50,
    // defines the time each call is held on buffer waiting for subsequent calls before aggregation, ms
    timeWindow: 50,
    // MultiCallUtils smart contract
    contract: '0xb39d1Dea1bF91Aef02484F677925904b9d6936B4',
  },
};
```

4. Wrap your ethers.js current provider with a Multicall provider:

```js
const multicallProvider = new providers.MulticallProvider(ethersProvider, multicallConfig[31]);
```

5. Connect your token smart contracts to the Multicall provider instead of ethers.js provider to be to able make aggregated calls:

```js
const token1 = new ethers.Contract(
    token1Address,
    token1ABI,
    multicallProvider,
  );
const token2 = ...
```

6. Now you are ready to create an aggregated call:

```js
function makeAggregatedCall() {
  const aggregatedCall = [
    multicallProvider.getBalance(address),
    token1.balanceOf(address),
    token1.allowance(owner, spender),
    token2.balanceOf(address),
    token2.allowance(owner, spender),
  ];
  [
    rbtcBalance,
    balance1,
    allowance1,
    balance2,
    allowance2,
  ] = await Promise.all(aggregatedCall);
}
```

The library will attempt to send all these function calls within a single call to `MultiCallUtils` smart contract `multiCall()` function.
However if the aggregated call fails,
as a fallback,
its constituent functions calls will be called individually via the ethers.js provider.

7. In order to subscribe to every newly minted block, attach the `makeAggregatedCall` function to the ethers provider `block` event listener:

```js
ethersProvider.on('block', makeAggregatedCall);
```

Comment: you can find the full [source code in the repo](https://github.com/rsksmart/demo-code-snippets/tree/master/multicall-0xsequence).

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`ethereum-multicall`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-multicall) project,
which consists of:

- [Frontend library](https://github.com/joshstevens19/ethereum-multicall) which connects to
- [Multicall3 smart contract](https://github.com/mds1/multicall)

#### Smart contract deployments:

The advantage of this project is that both Rootstock Mainnet and Rootstock Testnet have the `Multicall3` deployments:

- Mainnet [`0xcA11bde05977b3631167028862bE2a173976CA11`](https://explorer.rsk.co/address/0xca11bde05977b3631167028862be2a173976ca11)
- Testnet [`0xcA11bde05977b3631167028862bE2a173976CA11`](https://explorer.testnet.rsk.co/address/0xca11bde05977b3631167028862be2a173976ca11)

... and bonus points for the `0xca11...ca11` vanity address ;)

#### To make aggregated smart contract calls:

1. Install the npm package:

```bash
npm i ethereum-multicall
```

2. Import the library to your project:

```js
const { Multicall } = require('ethereum-multicall');
```

3. Create Multicall instance and connect it to ethers.js provider

```js
const multicall = new Multicall({
    ethersProvider: ethersProvider,
    tryAggregate: true,
});
```

4. Create aggregated call:

```js
  const aggregatedCall = [
    {
      reference: 'token1',
      contractAddress: token1Address,
      abi: token1ABI,
      calls: [
        {
          methodName: 'balanceOf',
          methodParameters: [walletAddress],
        },
        {
          methodName: 'allowance',
          methodParameters: [ownerAddress, spenderAddress],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      reference: 'token2',
      contractAddress: token2Address,
      abi: token2ABI,
      calls: [
        {
          methodName: 'balanceOf',
          methodParameters: [walletAddress],
        },
        {
          methodName: 'allowance',
          methodParameters: [ownerAddress, spenderAddress],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  const { results } = await multicall.call(aggregatedCall);
```

5. Extract the required data from the `results` object

Comment: Find [the source code in a repo](https://github.com/rsksmart/demo-code-snippets/tree/master/multicall-3)